# how make an uploaded a file can't use a characters the name in php

Tags: javascript, php

If the user uploads a file with a punctuated name (') ("), (&) etc, then a pop up" Please check the name of the uploaded file, hopefully not using characters ('), ("), (& ), and other possible characters to be the cause of failed upload file "

[if the file contains a character then show pop up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnHNx.png)

could it possible?

Comment: "could it be possible": yes, but in Javascript, not PHP. But why would you need this?

Comment: im in internship, and i was asked for adding some features in their web, that is one of the features. could you help me? i have no idea, i never studying javascript before.

Comment: if you use jQuery, you could do something like `$('fileinput').change(function(e) {if (e.target.files[0].name.indexOf('&')!=-1) alert("invalid file name");});`. You should tag this question javascript if you want to go in this direction.

Comment: i dont understand how to apply it, could you sent me a sample file please?

Comment: What do you study? If it's not about programming you should definitely ask them to give you another assignment. And especially if you also got access to the back-end of the site(php), a "rookie" should not be allowed to work on file uploads.

Comment: i studied programming in school like, php, java,html,c++. but i didn't study javascript. yeah i should tell them that i couldn't have done the file uploads

Comment: Also if you are in an internship, you should first ask your advisor/mentor before trusting some people from the internet

Answer (score 1):

Such requirement makes little sense. First, when a file is uploaded via php, it gets a temporary name and is stored in /temp folder. Then it is up to the server logic to move and rename the file. 
You of course can sanitize the original filename by replacing all undesired characters with "safe" characters, or return an error.

See here of how uploads work: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php